# How to create a list using HTML tags in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape the table data off the webpage below:

http://www.europeantour.com/europeantour/season=2016/tournamentid=2016056/leaderboard/index.html

Below is part of the code that I have written for this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webPage = 'http://www.europeantour.com/europeantour/season=2016/tournamentid=2016056/leaderboard/index.html'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(webPage) 
page = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
browser.close()

table = soup.find_all('div', class_='leaderboardTable RES')
rowdata = table[0].find(id = '1')
print(rowdata.prettify())
elem = rowdata.get_text()
elemList = elem.split()
print(elem)
print(elemList)
```

The list print(elemList) outputs the list below:

['1', 'CHAN', 'Shih-chang', 'TPE', '-12', '71', '67', '63', '67', '268', '122,047', '**', '€', '122,047']

The problem I have is that I need to output the two items - 'CHAN' & 'Shih-chang' - as one item (i.e. 'CHAN Shih-chang')

print(rowdata.prettify()) shows that they should be one item as per the output below:

```
<span class="hname">
 <a alt="Player Profile" href="/europeantour/players/playerid=33819/index.html" title="Player Profile">
  CHAN Shih-chang
 </a>
</span>
```

However, the elem.split() function separates them based on the spaces between them.

How do I create the list based on using the 'span' tags as item separators as opposed to the 'space' criteria used by the .split() function?

Any suggestions as to how to overcome this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apologies, I believe I have the answer via the code below:

Comment: item = rowdata.findAll('span')
    print(item)

Comment: Got confused between .find_all and .findAll